# How to change function of a button from expandable menu or long press menu

Tags: android

I'm trying to do an app for read news.

I have a layout and it has 5 imagebuttons and one webview. When I click a button it calls a website in webview. No problem this far but I want to develop it more.

I'm using these buttons like my favorites. So, (actually I'm not sure which is good) I will use expandable menu or long press menu for change functions and images of each button.
For example, 1st button for CNN news. But the user must have a chance to change his favorites. So from the expandable menu or longpress menu he must choose a site. When he chooses a site, the button's function (URL) and its image must change. But i really didnt figure out how I'd do it.

If I choose long press then how can I change the function (URL) of a button? The url and image must change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/
Follow this example to make a longpress then just have the menu it pops up contain a text input which returns the value of the text input.

Comment: thank you for ur answer but already i'm able to add a longpress menu..but now the problem that how can change ImageButton's image and its URL command.and surely it shouldnt change after close program too.

Comment: Can you post code of how you are handling the button click so I can help better?

Comment: i posted here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865258/how-to-change-function-of-a-button-and-its-image-from-expandable-menu
but i changed my button 's code : webview.loadUrl(getString(R.string.website1));